# Azure Data Factory - Not able to change data type Copy Activity Data Lake Storage to Synapse DW

Tags: xml, azure, azure-data-factory

I'm bulding a copy activity pipeline. My intetion is to copy multiple XML file from Blob/Datalake Storage to SQL Synapse database. I'm using the Automatically Create Table option. The error that I'm getting is:

> ErrorCode=UserErrorSchemaMappingCannotInferSinkColumnType,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Data type of column 'ide.dhSaiEnt' can't be inferred from 1st row of data, please specify its data type in mappings of copy activity or structure of DataSet.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'

It seems that I need to manually change the data type, but this option is not available in mapping section. I've already tried to import schemas, redo the mapping..but nothing works...

can anyone help me?

Comment: Do this in a data flow in ADF. You can change the data type in a Derived Column.

Comment: Hello Mark, actually it 's not...it's in Copy Data Activity..the auto mapping option. It seemed to be a bug, because I reestared the copy activity and was able to change the data types.